# Use wildcard with express.vhost

Tags: node.js, express, vhosts

Is `express.vhost` able to support a **wildcard** to catch all traffic of one specific domain? I'm looking for every subdomain (www.example.com, xyz.example.com) and the TLD itself (example.com).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, `express.vhost` supports wildcards since late 2010 when [CoolAJ86](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/express-js/MdpErniq40o) asked for it on GGroups:

```
// Will this work?

connect.vhost("*.example.com", function (req, res) {});
```

Well, it does now. But it's only receiving **all subdomains, not the TLD** itself.

Since you, great questioner (my earlier and maybe future self) are trying to catch everything related to the domain, its subdomains and their cats, you should **not** use two different routes simply out of desperation.

Just remove the first dot, *it's not that hard, idiot.*

```
connect.vhost("*example.com", function (req, res) {});
```

Comment: "Just remove the first dot, it's not that hard, idiot." - I thought you were being a bit of a dick to the OP, and then I realized YOU were the OP. +1

Comment: Wouldn't that also match otherexample.com, causing potential security issues?

Perhaps doing two vhosts for *.example.com and example.com would be better?

Comment: @gkoberger It requires some knowledge about the host, but it seems like it would be possible to set up an A record for "iheartcatsexample.com" and have it point to this server's IP. Although all it does is serve his content from another domain.